# Tense to use with "so far"

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, present-tense

Which tense should I use with **so far**
in the following sentences? I know we use present tense with **so far**. But I don't if it should be **present perfect** or **simple present**. I have provided some example sentences below. Please tell me which tense I should use.

1. My bike **is running/has been running** quite smoothly so far.
2. John: Hey Subha, how **is/(has)** your day (**been going**) so far? Me- It **is/has been** quite good so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"So far" means "up to now", which is what the present perfect continuous also means. So they go together nicely.

> My bike **has been running** smoothly so far. I hope it'll make it through the end of the week without needing to go to the shop.

That being said, the simple present is fine in the context of your second sentence:

> John: Hey Subha, **how's** your day going?
>   Subha:  **It's** good so far.