# AmE _ Simple past with the implication "so far"

Tags: grammar, american-english

A professor gave me a project, and now he wants me to update the the progress of the project I am doing.
I wonder if I can use the simple past "What **did** you do on the project" to imply so far in AmE:

> The professor: How is your project? What **did** you do on the project so far?
>
> Me: I only finished the first part of the project, I am going to
> proceed to study the next part tomorrow.

The question should be

(1) What did you do on the project (so far-imply)? or

(2) What have you done on the project (so far-imply)?

(3) Which part of the project did you finish (so far-imply)? or

(4) Which part of the project have you finished (so far-imply)?

I know that BrE definitely uses the present perfect. AmE also uses present perfect. I know that AmE tend to use simple past instead of the present perfect I don't know if AmE uses the simple past in this context.

Comment: As [this US chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+happened+so+far%3Aeng_us_2019%2CWhat+has+happened+so+far%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) and [this UK chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What+happened+so+far%3Aeng_gb_2019%2CWhat+has+happened+so+far%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show, there's no significant difference in US/UK verb forms before ***so far*** - we all tend to stick to Present Perfect. Why did you think there might be a difference?

Comment: The only difference between the sentences is that one is simple past tense (did), and the other is present perfect tense (have done). There is no real difference in their meanings. I would suggest not omitting the use of "so far", as it implies that there is still time remaining.

Comment: In and of itself, ***so far*** explicitly forces the focus of any containing utterance to be *specifically* concerned with the relationship between the present and something in the (recent) past. Which is *exactly* the context in which we nearly always use Present Perfect. That's all Anglophones, not just Brits.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that using present perfect tense (have done) with "so far" sounds a lot more natural.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tense to use with "so far".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167505/tense-to-use-with-so-far) As the answer there points out, *"So far" means "up to now", which is what the present perfect continuous also means. So they go together nicely.*

Comment: The prescriptivist gramma stickler in me would be tempted to say that the expression "What did you do on the project so far?" is straightforwardly an error.  I'm not all that familiar with American dialects, but the only time you'd hear such a sentence in my dialect would be if the speaker changed what they wanted to say mid-sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for your help. "Why did you think there might be a difference?"=> Because I know that in some case, where the present result is the most concern/ relevant,  the BrE will choose to use the present perfect, but the AmE prefer to use the simple past instead. For example: A mom hears a loud sound, she comes and sees, there is  a broken vase, then she asks the son (1) What happened/ (2) has happened? BrE will prefer (2), while AmE prefers to use (1). So that I would like to ask that in this context, If AmE also prefers to use the simple past instead.

Comment: @Mephisto, Thank you for your help. I would like to know, IN THIS CONTEXT, if an AmE speaker uses the past simple as in sentence (1) and (3) in my first post. Are these sentences in this context considered wrong in the US?

Comment: @Jaime: It's certainly not syntactically *invalid* to use Simple Past with ***so far*** - it's just stylistically unlikely in most contexts. But actually, there *could* be contexts where a competent native speaker would do this - for example, to imply that the addressee will *not* be working on the project in future (even if he doesn't know that yet! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in your dialect does "What did you do on the project so far?" imply anything that "What have you done on the project so far?" doesn't?  I don't see any difference in nuance between the two, except that the former seems at best linguistically awkward in my dialect? In particular, I can't see how it suggests any more than the latter that the addressee might have reasons to fear for his job.

Comment: @Jaime: You're confusing "linguistically awkward" and "syntactically invalid". As I said, the Simple Past is perfectly valid - it's just ***far less common*** in the context being discussed. And as usual, if a competent native speaker chooses to use a less common construction, this usually implies some contextually-relevant "different nuance". I just gave one possible example (boss asking the worker what he did, while implying that he will be taken off the project for unsatisfactory progress). That meaning isn't "automatically" present just from the non-standard tense choice, obviously.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't want to sound prickly, but I'm not confusing anything. And I'm still none the wiser on the answer to the question I put.  I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Well, I don't think I can explain the situation any better than I have already. Present Perfect implies a strong connection between a past action and the present (or future) situation. And ***so far*** does much the same, so they would *normally* go together. Hence if the speaker chooses *not* to use the Perfect in such contexts, obviously that ***weakens*** the link between the past and present - exactly what that shift in nuance "means" will depend heavily on the precise context.

Comment: I wouldn't find it at all odd for someone to include the words "so far" in such a sentence. Yes, use of the past tense implies, well, the past. But we often add words to a sentence that don't technically change the meaning, but add emphasis or clarity. "What have you done?" and "What have you done so far?" arguably are asking the same thing. But the second emphasizes that I want to know what is complete, not what you plan to do in the future.

Comment: @Jay, in the U.S , WITH THIS CONTEXT, both tenses are good to use with the meaning “so far”. Even the professor knows that the student haven’t finished the project yet. The simple past is also used to emphasize that the professor only wants to know what is complete/ what the student finished . The present perfect sounds like the professor want to know the current status/ progress of the project. Right?

Comment: @Jay would you use the simple past in this context: what did you do so far?

Comment: @LEHANH You could simply ask, "What did you do?" Or more likely in a context like this you'd use a past perfect, "What have you done?"

Comment: you'd use a past perfect, "What have you done?"=> I think you mean "the prsent perfect"; the past perfect is "What had you done"?